# What account does wordpress use to edit php files in windows?

Tags: account

I am trying to edit theme editor to edit files on wordpress, but I get the error about, the file is not writable. So now I want to give the account write permissions on the file, but I don't know which user account wordpress runs as on the website when editing files. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching is a Rol that has the capability [edit_themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_themes) which gives you access to the `Theme Editor` and to edit theme files.

If you see this [table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) only `Super Admin` (multisite) and `Admin` (single site) have that capability, so you need to add that rol to your users, now giving the rol `admin` will be dangerous, what you can is either create a new Rol and add the capability to the new Rol, or add the capability to an existing Rol.

Comment: I think I am referring to the windows local users type of account.  Like what account does wordpress run as in order to open and edit files on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php) and log into your site
2. In the remote site (right side), right click on the folder (including its sub items) that you'd like to change.
3. Go to `>wordpress>folder>wp-contant>upload>themes`
4. Select "File Attributes"
5. Select the "Recurse into subdirectories" option
6. If you've set 755 for the permissions, apply it to directories only
7. Then use 644 for files only

For more info prefer this page: [Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Each time, FileZilla will navigate through the folder and its subfolders 
changing the permission of each item appropriately. It may take several minutes for it to complete if you have many files.
Afterward, double check the permissions of some of the items, particularly for the main folder.

Comment: Its on a localhost windows server, not a external service.

Comment: hi @omega i would like to tell you , that localhost too have there ftp accounts :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an localhost or iis server , than i request you to change the file permission manually , by giving all permission to **IUSR**  and **IIS_IUSR** (iis User's)  if you are using iis server , or for local host give admin permission to htdocs

i hope this will help you a lot :)